# How can I order a queryset in Django by custom values?

Tags: python, django

I want to order result of a query (done by .filter) based on a list of values I provide.

I have a importance column in my database and the values are none, not important, important, very important. But when I make a query, Django returns whichever row is the first. I want to specify to put "very important" first, "important" second, "not important" third and the last would be none.

### Curent Query Result

```
1, word, not important
2, word2, none
3, word3, very important
4, word4, important
```

### Query result I want to achieve

```
3, word3, very important
4, word4, important
1, word, not important
2, word2, none
```

How can I make this order?

Comment: can you show your code? like the query? did you try using `oder_by("...")`. Your "important, very important etc" isnt very good for ordering. You can display these choices names for the user but you should save them as `0,1,2,3`  in your db. You could write a little script to replace the values from important to 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Django model field's choices options and map the values to an integer, based on the importance. Then it will be easier to sort and also it will boost performance up to some extent. Refer [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) for more information regarding implementation.

Your model may look something like the below example:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    IMPORTANCE_CHOICES = [
        (1, 'VeryImportant'),
        (2, 'Important'),
        (3, 'NotImportant'),    
]
    your_field_name = models.IntegerField(
        choices=IMPORTANCE_CHOICES,
        default=0,
    )
```

Please change the field definition as per your requirement.

Comment: Consider adding a line on how a query could look like with the Django ORM or raw SQL to make a better answer. Even when the question does not have code it does not hurt to write a line.

Comment: thanks for the input @hansTheFranz, I have recently started answering here. I will take care of your input next time onwards.